# c# chart interval with custom increase option

Tags: c#, charts

I am using C# Chart, and currently have:

```
mychart.chartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum=0;
mychart.chartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum=40;
mychart.chartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval=4;
```

This works fine, i.e., I get on x-axis 0, 4, 8, 12, etc... But is there a way to do interval to be power of 2 for example? I.e., I would get x-axis 0, 2, 4, 8, 16, etc. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're wanting a logarithmic X axis on powers of 2.

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IsLogarithmic = true;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LogarithmBase = 2;
```

Will generate a chart that renders it's X-axis like:

[image]

You can also render a minor grid with decades like you're likely used to seeing on a logarithmic chart, with this:

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 1;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = 64;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MinorGrid.Enabled = true;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MinorGrid.Interval = 0.1;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MinorGrid.LineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Dash;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IsLogarithmic = true;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LogarithmBase = 2;
```

renders:

[image]